# After ubuntu upgrade the cursor of the mouse is no more displayed

Tags: upgrade, 13.10, mouse, restore, cursor

I have just upgraded ubuntu and restarted. The problem is that when ubuntu started the cursor was no more displayed. I know that it is there because when I pass over a link it is underlined or when I pass over the launch bar it is shown the tool tip with the name of the application. The only thing that misses is the cursor.
I have already tried the solution described in [this page](https://askubuntu.com/questions/118001/how-to-restart-only-missing-invisible-mouse-pointer-cursor)  but with no result.
How can I show the cursor, or if it is not possible how can I restore the pc at the moment before the upgrade?

I'm working on ubuntu 13.10.

**Update:**
If I open the control panel(I search it from the dashboard), the cursor appears, but I have to do it every time I restart ubuntu. Moreover the window of the control panel is as in [the image](http://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/800x600q90/844/okdi.png)(Last time there were not the background green). Control Panel window is not the only program with the window distorted, there it also nautilus.

Comment: It happened to me switching to gnome 3.10, had to switch ligthDM for GDM. Please add information about which graphic interface you are using and which display manager, as well as the graphic card/driver.

Comment: How can I find this information?

Comment: If you haven't changed anything, the default graphic environment in  Ubuntu is Unity with LightDM. For the graphic card information, look at the control panel, under "details".

Comment: @Rmano I updated the question

Comment: Unfortunately I can't help --- but the linked image seems ok to me, it's very similar to mine. What's wrong with it?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like bug # 615938, which is set to expire shortly without more activity.
To provide more info to the bug, in a terminal run:

```
apport-collect -p xserver-xorg-input-evdev 615938
```

Also, do add yourself to the bug's "does this affect me" list.

Comment: ok, I added myself to the list. Now I shold just wait, or I can do something else?

Comment: Note the date on the bug.  Don't expect anything soon! You might experiment with different video drivers as well as different desktops.

Comment: so even with the future lst 14.04 the bug will not solve?