# stop spotify client killing mouse

Tags: 14.04, compiz, mouse, spotify

I have Ubuntu 14.04 and when I click in the spotify window, I lose the ability to click the mouse anywhere else. If I have a terminal already open I can run `compiz --replace` and get the mouse back. If I click in spotify again the same thing happens.

Any idea what is causing this or how to fix it?

Comment: Did you find an answer to this? Problem exists still today. Ubuntu 14.04, Spotify 9.17.1

Comment: No, it still happens occasionally, but not all the time. Its pretty frustrating

Comment: It happens when I do a quick alt-tab or move to another virtual desktop from Spotify for me. I end up having to restart compiz, which is essentially restarting my PC. I'm going to try to see if I can determine the problem better.

Answer (score 0):

**Spotify ([here](https://community.spotify.com/t5/Help-Desktop-Linux-Mac-and/BUG-Spotify-catches-all-mouse-clicks/m-p/310626#M34112)):**

Can you start spotify from a terminal window and see if it outputs any error messages when this occurs? (Ctrl+Alt+T) to open terminal and then type `spotify &`

To close spottily: select it and press `Alt+F4` or in a terminal type `killall spotify`.

**Mouse restart** (from [here](http://www.tuxtrix.com/2010/06/restarting-your-touchpadmouse-in-ubuntu.html) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/118001/how-to-restart-only-missing-invisible-mouse-pointer-cursor)):

If you are stuck with no mouse movement on your laptop (touchpad) then press the key combinations Alt+F2 and type in

```
gksudo modprobe -r psmouse
```

Type in the password, press enter, and then press Alt+F2 again for entering the following

```
gksudo modprobe psmouse
```

Thats it. Your mouse pointer will start working again.

If you like to do it through the terminal, then type in gnome-terminal after pressing Alt+F2
When the terminal open up type the following

```
sudo modprobe -r psmouse
sudo modprobe psmouse
```

If your usb mouse is getting stuck, then use the following command after pressing Alt+F2

```
gksudo /etc/init.d/hotplug restart
```