# Mouse cursor invisible after 15.04 update

Tags: mouse, 15.04, cursor

My mouse pointer became invisible after some updates after I upgraded to 15.04 from 14.10. 
In all standard settings the mouse pointer is activated (system settings, dconf...)
I also tried different cursor icons with no success.

The pointer is sometimes visible after I shut down and reboot the system. But only sometimes and I couldn't figure out a patterns why it sometimes shows up.

I found the following solution which did not work

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.cursor active false
```

Any help appreciated! thanks!

Comment: Happened the same to me upgrading to 14.04. I think it's a bug/interaction for having had both gnome and unity installed. Apart from the command you mention, I had to [switch from lightDM to GDM.](http://askubuntu.com/questions/152256/how-do-i-switch-from-lightdm-to-gdm)

Comment: Did you post a bug report?

Comment: As of 2017-03-22 this problem has been solved by an update.

Answer (score 47):

This bug is still around for a Xubuntu 16.04 system using lightdm. A fix for Xubuntu, and possibly other DE's, as described on the [Xubuntu 16.04 Release Post](http://xubuntu.org/news/xubuntu-16-04-release/) is to bring the cursor back with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> followed by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> .

This worked for me, where none of the other solutions had without reloading everything and closing every page.

Comment: As of 2016-06-04 this seems to be the best solution in that 1) it actually works (unlike the gsettings or modprobe suggestions) and 2) doesn't involve killing all of your open applications by restarting lightdm.

Comment: Note to the less Linux-experienced such as myself: `Ctl+Alt+F1` will (somewhat frighteningly) drop you into a full-screen virtual terminal session. `Ctrl+Alt+F7` will drop you back into your previous desktop session with all of your windows intact.

Comment: Didn't solve the issue. Using Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS. dopsar's answer below worked though.

Comment: Works on Ubuntu 17.10 as well.

Answer (score 30):

I have the same problem after upgrading to 15.04 from 14.10. Sometimes the mouse pointer will appear, this happens approx 1 in 5 computer switch on times. I found a way to get round this as suggested above.

(note: this will hard-kill any running processes).

`sudo service lightdm restart`

This does have to be issued after every start up . Does anybody know of a more long-term fix?

I have now found a long-term fix. Switch to gdm instead.

`sudo apt-get install gdm`

after trying several reboots this fix seems to work every time.

I don't know if `lightdm` gives any advantages over `gdm`, but to me seeing the cursor is a big advantage of GDM over lightdm.

Comment: After over 2 month of trying I also switched to gdm... thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: Mind explaining what restarting lightdm does? Does it really "blank out" your screen (it did to me)?

(I was hoping I could get my mouse pointer back without restarting because there's a lot I'm working on. So I tried this out and it blanked out my screen. Ended up doing a manual restart. Is that really supposed to happen?)

Comment: Thank you, finally I found a solution,  ctrl+alt+f1 then execute sudo service lightdm restart...

Comment: Hey! RE: `sudo service lightdm restart`, that just hard-killed every app and a virtual machine I was running. You might want to add a little warning about that to your answer.

Comment: I switched to gdm, and the computer didn't start at all!

Comment: On lubuntu this killed all applications running... this is not a good answer

Answer (score 13):

A dirty hack I do (which surprisingly works for me) is to open terminal by pressing `Ctrl+Alt+T` and then type `ls` then the mouse shows in 1-2 seconds.

That said, the normal way that works is to restart the mouse driver. This solution also works when the mouse pointer is misbehaving (like flickering randomly out of control). You restart the mouse driver like:

```
sudo modprobe -r psmouse  # disable the driver
sudo modprobe psmouse # enable the mouse driver
```

Comment: Odd shortcut, but if it works...

Comment: `ls` in terminal works fine in Xubuntu 16.04 Beta 2. Of course restating lightdm works as well.

Comment: Nothing about `ls` as far as I can tell. Just opening a terminal and pressing return brings the cursor back. Maybe the terminal is also a red herring...

Comment: works on 14.04.

Answer (score 7):

I have similar problem. Mouse pointer is invisible after system boot, even on LightDM screen. To bring cursor back I'm switching to virtual console (ctrl+alt+f1) and run command:

```
sudo service lightdm restart
```

After LightDM restart mouse pointer back to normal. I reported this bug to [Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lightdm/+bug/1453538).

Answer (score 5):

Open a terminal <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> and type `sudo apt-get install lightdm --reinstall` then `sudo shutdown -r now` to reboot. This worked for me and I've tested it by rebooting several times.

Comment: This one did it for me as well on 15.04

Comment: It worked for me also

Comment: Did not work for me on 14.04

Comment: Clearly the most reasonable answer. Everything else is merely a temporary or hacky workaround.

Comment: This worked for me.
4.4.0-79-generic
Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Answer (score 3):

There can be some problems of this kind if you have got nvidia optimus technology in your computer. Try to use different driver (e.g. Noveau display driver) from `Additional Drivers` tab in `Software & Updates`.

Comment: Thanks! But I'm not using nvidia optimus though. I only have an integrated graphics card

Comment: If you go to tty1 (`ctrl+alt+f1`) and then back to gui (`ctrl+alt+f7`), does you cursor appear correctly?

Comment: No, unfortunately not :(

Comment: I have a GK107GLM (Quadro K1100M). I experienced this issue and solved it by opening the `Additional Drivers` panel and just clicking on another driver (one of the NVIDIA proprietary ones). Just clicking on another driver resolved the problem. I didn't even have to apply the changes.

Comment: Strange, do you have another driver highlighted now?

Comment: Thanks, worked for me, but vise versa: Noveau produces cursor disappearing, while NVIDIA proprietary works correctly.

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu do you use? `sudo do-release-upgrade` can install you the newest Xorg if you want, but if it works, don't touch your drivers. I find ubuntu graphics extremely unstable, as I have some problems for 2 or 3 years, and I dare not to do anything with working drivers.

Answer (score 3):

I fixed it by going to displays setting (write dis in search bar) and than turned off the "`unknown display"`. U see in displays setting two displays in the middle of picture in settings. One is built-in-display another is unknown. Choose unknown by clicking on it on the picture and take the button next to the "Unknown Display" from on to off. Tada

Answer (score 2):

From [this post](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2252957) on Ubuntu forums, running this command in a terminal fixed this issue

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.cursor active false
```

This works intermittently for me... and I don't know yet why it works at times and not others, but. may help you too.

Comment: In my post you can see that I already tried this method and it doesn't work for me

Comment: Confirmed to work with Synergy 1.8.7-stable-9799e96 on Ubuntu 16.04 while sharing a mouse from macOS 10.12.2.

Answer (score 2):

Issuing the following command will restart compiz (the window manager and decorator), without loosing your desktop and loging out (like restarting lightdm would):

```
sudo killall -i -HUP compiz
```

That brought my cursor back when it disappeared, while keeping all my windows and my currently working programs.

Comment: Thank you, this was the ONLY command that worked when all other didn't work (other than restart lightdm which I dont want to do)

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem as well, it seems like replacing gnome-setings-daemon with unity-settings-daemon seems to fix this problem.

Comment: I removed gnome-settings-deamon and unity-settings-deamon was already installed but no change occured. Is that what you meant? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this:

```
 gsettings set org.settings.daemon-plugins.cursor -KEY=s.cursor -VALUE=false
```

and it might work fine this way.

Comment: I get: No such schema 'org.settings.daemon-plugins.cursor'

Answer (score 1):

This is [a very old Unity bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity-greeter/+bug/1453538) to which that are references that date back to 13.04. Given that Unity version 7 is reaching its end of life, probably it will never be fixed. For a while, logging out and logging back in would temporarily revive the mouse pointer, but this workaround no longer does it on Ubuntu 14.04. The `gsettings set` command is not functional on 14.04 either.

However, this problem can be fixed on 14.04 by issuing this command:

`setsid unity`

This will reset all your Unity options, number of workspaces, launcher size, etc. But better that than not having the mouse pointer.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu 16.04 and Gnome Flashback here.
The mouse cursor would disappear during login.  Similar fix as mentioned above.
I used "dconf Editor" and searched for "cursor".  I found the value that fixed the issue in the location:

org,gnome,desktop,settings-daemon,plugins,cursor,active

I unticked active and my mouse come back instantly and is surviving restarts.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by deleting my .config folder from my home dir (~) after noticing the issue only appeared on one user. While not ideal it is a possible fix.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem on 15.04. At one point the mouse cursor suddenly disappeared, but when I moved to another workspace (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Arrow</kbd>) it reappeared.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @DavidFoerster It is an answer. My point is that switching to a different workspace might solve the issue, at least for some users; it worked for me.

Comment: but this is not a proper solution, but a work around!

Comment: Didn't work for me on Ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 0):

Doing this solved the problem for some of the users:   install dconf-editor

`sudo apt-get install dconf-editor`

and change the icon size to smaller in settings.
That seems to solve the issues

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I solved the problem:

Create a shell script (yourscript.sh) with this code:

```
#!/bin/bash
service lightdm restart
```

As root, move it to the /etc/init.d folder
Then, open the folder in the terminal and run:

```
chmod 755 yourscript.sh
```

Then, while in terminal, enter this command:

```
ln -s /etc/init.d/yourscript.sh /etc/rc2.d/S99yourscript.sh
```

Now, your mouse pointer will appear at every boot and the problem of the invisible mouse pointer should be gone.

References:

https://askubuntu.com/a/290107

https://askubuntu.com/a/629965/462410

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue after upgrading to 16.04. I tried to install gdm as suggested by @user417467 but this didn't solve the problem so I reverted back to lightdm. I found that after logging back I can make the pointer reappear simply by pressing `crtl+F7`.

Answer (score 0):

Setup: Ubuntu 14.04 with default installation. I have automatic login enabled as well.

For me, I simply log off and log in again. At the login screen the mouse cursor returns and remains till next restart. Works every time for over 50 times now.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem upgrading Lubuntu 14.04 to Lubuntu 16.04. Cursor disappear after resume. <kbd>Ctr</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F1</kbd> ,  <kbd>Ctr</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F7</kbd> solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by plugging an unused wireless mouse dongle in to keep the driver happy.

Comment: I always have a wireless mouse plugged in and it still happens.

Comment: This is the first answer on this page that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Well, On Ubuntustudio 16.04, I found out that if I get the mouse to hover the button for the app menu, and start to browse, it comes right back no problem!!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on XUbuntu 15.10.

The only working way I found to get back the cursor is:

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> (open the terminal)
2. `sudo apt-get install gnome-screensaver`
3. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> (lock screen)
4. got the cursor back...

Answer (score 0):

I came here from google because I have been experiencing the same problem in ubuntu `16.04` . The last several times it has happened, i was reliably able to get the mouse back by simply opening a terminal using <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>t</kbd> .

better than having to reboot every time.

Answer (score 0):

The top few answers did not work for me, however I managed to solve my problem by unplugging and re-plugging my USB mouse.

Answer (score -1):

I had to create a file called:

20-intel.conf // I'm using intel graphics

place the file on:

/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/

Using these lines:

```
Section "Device"
        Identifier  "card0"
        Driver      "intel"
        Option      "Backlight"  "intel_backlight"
        Option      "AccelMethod" "uxa"
        Option      "SWCursor" "on"
        BusID       "PCI:0:2:0"
EndSection
```