# Dissapeared cursor after install Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, cursor

1. I had installed Ubuntu 14.04 on my desktop, all worked correctly. After installation of needed software I made reboot and received message "The system is running in low-graphics mode” and black screen.
2. I've reinstalled Ubuntu from flash drive (cursor was visible in BIOS and on Ubuntu setup), installation completed successfully, after reboot cursor disappeared. I've tried to follow advice from Stack Overflow and installed Gdm instead of LightDm - after installation black screen appeared and reboot did not help to start Ubuntu.

What I can try to do in this situation? Now I have Ubuntu reinstalled, cursor is not visible.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in Ubuntu 14.04 and solved following the instruction in this post http://itsfoss.com/invisible-mouse-cursor-ubuntu-1310/ :

- Open a terminal Window (CTRL + ALT + T)
- Execute the following command:

  gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.cursor active false

Hope it helps :-)

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I've the same problem as well. Please see my question [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/686584/invisible-mouse-pointer).

You'll see that [it's a bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-settings-daemon/+bug/1390628), so there's not much one can do.