# Battery icon on top-right takes a long while to come after switching from Unity to GNOME Desktop

Tags: 14.04, unity, gnome, power-management, battery

I've recently switched from `unity` to `ubuntu-gnome-desktop` on my inspiron laptop running 14.04 LTS. After I reconfigured `gdm` as primary display manager and logged into the new desktop, I faced two issues:

1. The mouse cursor was not appearing for a long time. This was thankfully solved after I made the following `dconf` settings as per [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/655265/49938):
       gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.cursor active false
2. My other issue however, still stays. As soon as I'm logged in, the battery-indicator on the top-right is not visible for a long time. Is there a similar `gsettings` configuration for that too?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by upgrading to `gnome 3.12`.