# Mouse locks up after period of no use

Tags: mouse, shutdown, lockup

My gateway laptop mouse pointer locks after a while of no use.
I am referring to built in touch pad.

How can I shutdown without a mouse?
How can I restart the mouse?
How can I eliminate the problem?

Per a suggestion I ran

```
larry@larry-Satellite-C70-A:~$ xinput
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ TOSHIBA Web Camera - HD                   id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Toshiba input device                      id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Comment: Is it a wireless mouse? Can you tell more about hardware?

Comment: Can you run `xinput` from the terminal and edit your question to include the output? (This doesn't mean that I know the answer - it is just something you should probably include so that others can better help you.)

Comment: Also, see [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/118001/how-to-restart-only-missing-invisible-mouse-pointer-cursor) for *maybe* an answer and a work-around until you get an answer.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me with a similar problem (might not work if you don't have a Synaptic touchpad).

- Open terminal (Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>T</kbd>)
- Type `synclient TouchpadOff=0` and press enter. This should reactivate the Touchpad.

If you just need to turn off your computer without a mouse, just open terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>T</kbd>) and type:

```
sudo poweroff
```

For a restart type:

```
sudo reboot
```

Comment: Thanks, doesn't work on my gateway which has the problem. Does turn the touchpad on and off on my Toshiba Satellite.

Comment: Alas.. It was worth a shot. And your question implied you also want to know how to shut down your computer w/o a mouse. So I added that to the answer.

Comment: Yes I did, and now I know, thanks to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Since I submitted this question I have worked out a solution to it.

Recovering from a hung mouse pointer is "easy to do" if you have
my script "mykitty" installed.

To install it just copy it from the public folder at
https://spideroak.com/browse/share/lle_public1/lle
to your home folder.

Then open a terminal window by hitting the t key while holding down the control and alt keys. Hit the enter key.

At the prompt, enter   ./mykitty -h  then hit the enter key.
The help text will be displayed.

When your mouse hangs
run  ./mykitty       to get the mouse running again.

If that fails to free the mouse
run  ./mykitty -r     to restart your system.

If you find this solution to is useful, please promote it.
Otherwise you have been reminded that "easy to do is easy to say".