# My mouse pointer has vanished. Can anyone please help me get it back?

Tags: mouse, unclutter

I'm running a really long job on my computer and my mouse pointer has just vanished. I really don't want to have to restart the computer because this is a very long job, so could anyone help me try to get the mouse pointer back?

Following [this solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/165092/204323), I have tried installing `unclutter` and then running it with the following command:

```
unclutter -idle 1 -root -grab -visible
```

This is supposed to make the mouse pointer vanish if it is idle for 1 second and reappear when it is no longer idle. Unfortunately, this hasn't worked and the mouse pointer has remained invisible. From [this idea](http://itsfoss.com/invisible-mouse-cursor-ubuntu-1310/), I've also tried running the following command:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.cursor active false
```

Unfortunately, it hasn't worked either.

Could anyone help? I'm on Ubuntu 15.04.

Comment: Maybe kill this "unclutter" thing? `sudo killall unclutter`?

Comment: Have you unplugged the mouse from the USB port then plugged it back in?

Comment: @EduardoCola Hey, thanks for the suggestion. The pointer vanished *before* I installed `unclutter`. I installed that program to see if it would cause the pointer to become visible again. I have killed it and the pointer is still invisible.

Comment: @Terrance Thanks for the suggestion. I've just given it a try. It didn't work unfortunately.

Comment: @d3pd It was just a thought as it has happened to me more than once.   Maybe [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/645/how-do-you-reset-a-usb-device-from-the-command-line) might have some suggestions on restarting USB to see if that helps.

Comment: @Terrance Thanks again. I feel I should clarify: the mouse is still working and it is obviously moving and interacting with things on the display, the problem is that the pointer is invisible. This leads me to think that it's solely a software problem.

Comment: @d3pd Ah, OK.  I think I was thinking something completely different then.  Almost like the mouse software itself needs to be restarted then.  If I can duplicate your issue and fix it without rebooting, I will definitely let you know.  =)

Comment: If you switch to a virtual term (ctrl-alt-f2) then switch back (ctrl-alt-f7) does the mouse reappear?  If you start a new x server, does it have a mouse? xinit /usr/bin/xterm -- :1 vt8
Does the mouse reappear on the first Xterm when you switch back?