# How to restart mouse stuck in scroll mode

Tags: 16.04, mouse, mouse-scroll

My mouse cursor is stuck in `scroll mode`, and a left click functions like a right click, and it doesn't go back to normal until I restart.

I've considered this solution:
[How to restart only missing/invisible mouse pointer/cursor?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/118001/how-to-restart-only-missing-invisible-mouse-pointer-cursor#118009)

but it does not work.

Disabling and re-enabling the touchpad in `Mouse & Touchpad` settings completely freezes my pointer. Restarting the device fixes the problem. Is there a way to reload my mouse pointer when this happens?

Comment: My Dell Precision 5530 is also affected by this. Running Linux burani-dell 4.18.0-13-generic #14-Ubuntu SMP Wed Dec 5 09:04:24 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: My issue was due to water spilling on it. I don't have this issue on a wireless mouse, and my wireless mouse resets the touchpad when it gets stuck now.

Comment: I see you have a work around using your mouse, so I'm slow to answer with a solution/work around that may not be applicable, but it certainly was a solution for me. Hence the comment here, instead of an answer.

My cursor has frequently gotten stuck in scroll mode on my new laptop/Ubuntu 19.04. It specifically has gotten stuck often times immediately after scrolling via my trackpad.

I've found when it's stuck, if I touch my trackpad with my fingers slightly spread apart (similar action to get into mouse scroll) it takes it out of scroll mode and my cursor is able to move again as desired.